# Оставить открытым DialogFragment

Tags: java, android

Необходимо что бы при нажатии на кнопку, диалог не закрывался.
При нажатии на кнопку если условие выполняется то диалог закрываеться, если нет, то остается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если внутри `DialogFragment` используется `AllertDialog`, то надо в качестве обработчика для кнопки установить `null`

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());        
    // какая то настройка диалога
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.more, null);
    return builder.create();
}
```

А в методе `onStart()` класса `DialogFragment` переопределить слушателя у кнопки следующим образом

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog) getDialog();
    if (dialog != null) {
        Button negative = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        //напрямую переопределяем слушателя для кнопки "Отмена" для предотвращения закрытия диалога
        negative.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // обработка условия и закрытие диалога
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dialogFragment.setCancelable(false);
```